# How to set openRawResourceId value in Android?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have raw folder and inside that I have added 3 `mp3` files. And am retrieving the file name like this:

```
Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
    Log.e("RawName: ", fields[count].getName());
}
String resid=fields[0].getName();
```

I just need only 0th position file. Now I have set the value like this,

```
   AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test);
    // Build and start first player
   MediaPlayer player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
    player1.start();
  MediaPlayer  player2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
```

My question is how can I set the value resid in to that "R.raw.test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        Log.e("RawName: ", fields[count].getName());
    }
    String resid=fields[0].getName();
    try {
        Class res = R.raw.class;
        Field field = res.getField(resid);
         rawId = field.getInt(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
    }

    /*music repeat*/
    afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(rawId);
    // Build and start first player
    player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawId);
    player1.start();
    player2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawId);
    player1.setNextMediaPlayer(player2);
```